# Growth of Functions, Big-O

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that $(x^2 + xy + x\log(y))^{3}$ is $O(x^6y^3)$.

How do I go about solving this?

I don't quite understand Big-O notation, all I know is that we must find some C and K but Idk how to find that.

Comment: Is the $xlog(y)$ term meant to be cubed or the entire expression?

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you @JackPfaffinger

Answer (score 3):

Well $f\left(n\right)$ is in $O\left(g\left(n\right)\right)$ if $f\left(n\right) \leq C *g\left(n\right)$ for all $n \geq k$ with $n, k >0$.

Consider $\left(x^2 + xy + x\log \left(y\right)\right)^3$, it is certainly the case that $u >\log \left(u\right)$ for all $u >0.$ Additionally $u^2 > u$ for all $u > 1,$ and $xy > x$ for $x, y > 1$.

Therefore it is true that : $\left(x^2y+x^2y + x^2y\right)^3 \geq \left(x^2 + xy + x\log \left(y\right)\right)^3$ for all $x ,y \geq1.$

Simplifying the LHS we have $\left(3x^2y\right)^3 = 27x^6y^3$

So going back to the beginning we need to show that $\left(x^2 + xy + x\log \left(y\right)\right)^3 \leq C*\left(x^6y^3\right)$ for some $x , y \geq k$.

Well we have: $\left(x^2 + xy + x\log \left(y\right)\right)^3 \leq 27\left(x^6y^3\right)$ for $x, y >0 $ and thus we are done.

Answer (score 1):

You want
$(x^2 + xy + x\log(y))^{3}
$.

One thing to know
is that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\log(x)}{x^c}
=0$ for any $c > 0$.
This means that
$\log(x) = O(x^c)$
for any $c>0$.

Therefore
$xy+x\log(y) = O(xy)$.

Also, obviously,
$x^2 = O(x^2)$.

A general equation is that
$x^ay^b = O(x^cy^d)$
if and only if $a \le c, b \le d$.

Therefore a sum of the form
$\sum x^{a_i}y^{b_i}$
is $O(x^uy^v)$
if each $a_i \le u, b_i \le v$,
or $u \ge \max(a_i), v \ge max(b_i)$.

Therefore
$x^2+xy = O(x^uy^v)$
if $u \ge \max(2, 1) = 2$
and
$v \ge \max(0, 1) = 1$,
so that
$x^2+xy = O(x^2y)$.

Now cube this.